# Refresh a form after submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to create a form that will check it fills; if true, refresh itself after submit button is clicked.
`viewing.php` post to be display in earliest submission first with timestamp in descending order.
I have this connected to my local database to store and display data entered.

I have tried every code from forums and youtube but nothing works.

Below is the code:

index.php:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    body {
        left:20px;
        font-size:15pt;
    }
    label, input, textarea{
        left:20px;
        margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
        font-size:15pt;
    }
    div {
        width:50%;
        background-color:lightgrey;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>    
<div> <!--id="auto"-->
    <form  name="ajax" action="insert.php" method="post" id="contact">
        <br>
    <label>Please Enter Your Comments :</label>
        <br><br>
    <label>Name :<span>*</span>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off"/>
    </label>
        <br>
    <label>Enter Your Wishes : <span>*</span>
        <br>
    <textarea name="Comment" rows="10" cols="30" id="Comment" placeholder="Message" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
    </label>
        <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="aa();"/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>

    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    location.refresh(true);

    $('#contact').submit(function () {
        sendContactForm();
    return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['Name'], $_POST['Comment'])){
    $fields = [
        'Name' => $_POST['Name'],
        'Comment' => $_POST['Comment']
    ];

    foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
        if (empty($data)){
            $errors[] = 'The '.$field . ' field is required.';
        }
    }
}
else {
    $errors[] = 'Error.';
}

// This function will run within each post array including multi-dimensional arrays 
function ExtendedAddslash(&$params)
{ 
    foreach ($params as &$var) {
        // check if $var is an array. If yes, it will start another ExtendedAddslash() function to loop to each key inside.
        is_array($var) ? ExtendedAddslash($var) : $var=addslashes($var);
        unset($var);
    }
} 

// Initialize ExtendedAddslash() function for every $_POST variable
ExtendedAddslash($_POST); 

$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Comment = $_POST['Comment'];

/*$db_host = 'localhost:8889';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'root';
$db_name = 'Event';*/

mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name); 

// search submission ID

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'demo' WHERE 'Name' = '$ID'";
$sqlsearch = mysql_query($query);
$resultcount = mysql_numrows($sqlsearch);

if ($resultcount > 0) {

    mysql_query("UPDATE `demo` SET 
                                `Name` = '$Name',
                                `Comment` = '$Comment',     
                             WHERE `ID` = '$ID'") 
     or die(mysql_error());

} else {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `demo` (ID, Name, Comment) VALUES ('$ID','$Name', '$Comment') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

}

header('Location: index.php');
?>'
```

viewing.php:

```
        <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            body {
                font-size:20pt;
            }   
        </style>        

<body>
<?php
require 'config.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

// Create connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Name, Comment FROM demo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Comment</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo "<tr><td>".$row["Name"]." ".$row["Comment"]."</td></tr>";
        echo "<fieldset>From : ".$row["Name"]."<br>".$row["Comment"]."<br></fieldset><br>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
/*Configuration Settings*/
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'root';
$db_name = 'Event';
$db_host  = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;
$socket = 'localhost:/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock';

?>
```

Comment: whats in `sendContactform()`? What doesnt work? have you any errors? `insert.php` probably wont work as youre trying to send headers after outputing html. You are also mixing mysql drivers (albeit not in the same page).  You have `myql_` in one page (which is deprecated and shouldnt be used), and you have `mysqli_` in another.  Is this a collection of snippets that youve put together in the hope it works?  Im afraid its not that simple.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `location.reload(true)`? And you might want to put it inside your script.

Comment: Yup, majority is from a coder.
Because I'm still in the process of learning php language.
The sendContactform() is a random code that doesnt do anything so if i were to take it away, it should not affect my codes. "thought if I inserted this, my form would keep refreshing after submission."
@DevDonkey

Comment: @DevDonkey
As to answer your questions:
What doesn't work?:
It is not checking the form if filled, then send. 
Have any errors?:
No errors printed out so far. So sometimes it hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
Thank you @Logan Wayne; your code helped
Now that i have the form refreshing after every entry, how do I get Viewing.php to fadeout and fadein only the latest entry;
Can viewing.php keep checking db for new entry and only display the newest entry after a certain time? 
Yes ive heard of fadein and fadeout, though not sure how to use it.
And also, how do I show some kind of loading bar base on timer or an alert once submit has been pressed? To show that data is submitted?
Thank you guys!!

Comment: Obligatory warning: `ExtendedAddslash()` is poor advise and will NOT prevent SQL injections. addslashes itself is insufficient to account for charset variations. See also: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)